# Receber atributo backgroud-image de uma div

Tags: c#, background

Estou tentando receber assim:

```
var obj = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("senderscore").GetAttribute("background-image")
```

mas ele retorna vazio.

O campo `background-image` da `div` contem uma url. E pertence a uma classe.

Estou errando por passar o comando errado, ou por não tentar pegar pela classe?

Tentei várias maneiras e não consegui.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Comment: Já tentou colcocar ali em vez de GetAtribute, AddClass ? E faz a classe no css e declara ela diretamente na div.

Comment: estou tentando pegar a url da imagem e não adicionar érik

Comment: `background-image` não seria do css do elemento, dentro do atributo style? Ou `background-image` é nome do atributo personalizado?

Comment: Thomas, background-image esta dentro do atributo style

Answer (score 2):

Com o método abaixo você consegue pegar tanto os atributos definidos no CSS quanto os atributos calculados pelo browser.

```
var elemento = document.getElementById("senderscore");
var estilo;
if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    estilo = getComputedStyle(elemento)
} else {
    estilo = elemento.currentStyle
}
var obj = estilo.getPropertyValue("background-image");   
alert(obj);
```

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado Isaac pela resposta. Mas eu estou tentando receber o link da background-image através de um WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

### Não entendi ao certo o que procura, se quer salvar a url em uma variável, [neste link](http://jsfiddle.net/subversivo58/9aYWs/1/)! Talvez lhe ajude.

```
$(function() {
     $("#senderscore").each(function() {
        var bg = $(this).css('background-image');
        bg = bg.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
        alert(bg);//alert para mostrar como a url fica armazenada na variável bg
    });
});

//requer jquery 1.9.1 (onLoad!)
```

Comment: Obrigado Lauro pela resposta. Mas eu estou tentando receber o link da background-image através de um WebBrowser.

Answer (score 0):

Para buscar o valor de uma propriedade do css de um determinado elemento usando `jQuery`, podemos utilizar da função [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

```
//Aqui retorna o valor do background-image
$('#id').css('background-image');
//Enquanto aqui o background-image vai receber o valor 'none'
$('#id').css('background-image', 'none');
```

Agora, se você não pode ou não quer utilizar o jQuery, existe uma forma de fazer isso apenas com Javascript.

```
var element, style, backgroundimage;
element = document.getElementById('id');
style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
backgroundimage = style.getPropertyValue('background-image');
```

Fonte: [SOEn: Get a CSS value with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338217/get-a-css-value-with-javascript)

**@EDIT**

Não havia percebido que você estava utilizando um `WebBrowser`, sendo assim tente acessar o atributo `Style` do elemento retornado pelo `GetElementById`. Exemplo:

```
var obj = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("senderscore").Style
```

Ai utilizando esta propriedade tu consegue procurar o `background-image` dentro da `String`.
Fonte: [MSDN HtmlElement.Style Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.style%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Obrigado Marciano pela resposta. Mas eu estou tentando receber o link da background-image através de um WebBrowser.

Comment: @VictorDelicoli da uma olhada na minha resposta denovo, editei a mesma.